# Upload file - Make input visible (Error: ElementNotVisibleException)

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

**Currently I have this input**

```
<label class="bold grey-rectangle" data-uploading="Uploading" data-completed="Upload completed">
  <span>+ Add certificate</span>
  <input type="file" data-validation-allowing="jpg, jpeg, pdf" data-validation="mime" name="qualification2">
  <div class="spinner hidden">
  <div class="spinner-inner"></div>
  </div>
</label>
```

**and I want to send a file to the same, so I'm running the following codes:**

```
self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('qualification2')[0].style.display='block';")
self.driver.find_element_by_name("qualification2").send_keys("certificate.jpeg")
```

**but I'm getting the following error**

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

**How, effectively, I can do an upload with python and selenium?**

Comment: Are you sure there are no other elements with the same `name` value?

Comment: I'm sure, this name is unique!

Comment: Thanks, could you please inspect the element in the browser developer tools and see how exactly it is made invisible?..

Comment: I think that some attributes are not fixed to this input. See the code now:

`<input class="hide" type="text" data-validation-error-msg-container="#qualification-error-dialog" data-validation-error-msg="You must upload a qualification" name="qualification" required="" data-validation="required">`

CSS:

`.hide {
    display: none !important;`

Answer (score 2):

You should try *removing the `hide` class* to make the element visible:

```
elm = self.driver.find_element_by_name("qualification2")
self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].removeAttribute("class");', elm)

elm.send_keys("/absolute/path/to/certificate.jpeg")
```

---

Used the link you've provided, tested it:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://your/site")

elm = driver.find_element_by_name("qualification2")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].removeAttribute("class");', elm)

elm.send_keys("/Users/user/Downloads/test.jpg")
```

Produced:

[image]

Note that in Firefox you would also have to reset the `margin-left` style property to 0 to make the element really visible:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].removeAttribute("class"); arguments[0].style["margin-left"] = 0;', elm)
```

Comment: Worked fine, but when I try load my file, is sent only a string: See: http://screencast.com/t/zbMAz2swr You can help me with this?

Comment: @Rafael interesting, according to the screenshot, it does not look like a file input, but a regular input instead..is this a public site tat you can share a link to? Thanks.

Comment: Is not a public site, How I can send URL to you via PM?

Comment: @Rafael we should trigger a suggestion to continue the discussion in chat.

Comment: Got it. remove my site

Comment: @Rafael please see the update in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Rafael also added a special trick for Firefox. Hope it helps.

Comment: still with problem. Check if are right, please: http://screencast.com/t/9Zp5NED56cHF

Comment: @Rafael okay, but why are you finding the `qualification` and not `qualification2`? Also, you need to specify and absolute path to the image file..

Comment: @alexce - name fixed. Path `elm.send_keys("../tests/certificate.jpeg/")` right?

Comment: @Rafael the path should be absolute, you can use `os.abspath()` for that by the way.